# Efficient list operations?

Tags: list, haskell

I have the following function that searches through [Char] and returns [Char] based on their index number:

```
myList = "abcdefghijk"

searchText = foldl (\acc el -> if elemIndex el myList > Just 11 then el : acc else acc) [] myList
```

Clearly this is somewhat inefficent as elemIndex returns the index number of each element then applies the condition.

Is there a more efficient way of performing this operation?

Comment: `drop 12 myList`?

Comment: To reproduce the exact semantics of the posted code is tricky, since there might be more than one occurrence of a character in `myList`. However, I think you might be OK with something very close to that. Can you express in plain words what is the task you want to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to pair each character with its index before doing the real processing

```
process $ zip [0..] myList
```

Now `process` can perform the actual computation, which can use the indexes as well as the characters.

In some contexts, this approach is known as the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a string that skips the first twelve characters and reverses the output, dropping any characters that are also in those first twelve.

For a more efficient version of this, you could use `Data.Set` to store those first twelve characters for fast lookup, the filter them out and reverse the remainder of the string:

```haskell
import qualified Data.Set as Set

searchText =
    let hash = (Set.fromList . take 12) myList
    in (reverse . filter (flip Set.notMember hash) . drop 12) myList
```